# Access env['warden'].user from ApplicationCable is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt, actioncable, devise-jwt

So I am trying to implement `dervise-jwt` in a Rails 5.2 application. My login is working properly, and the tokens are being created. That being said, I want to access that same `current_user` from my ActionCable. Following some online tutorials, my `app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb` looks like this:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    private

    def find_verified_user
      if user == env['warden'].user
        user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I debug the code, `env['warden'].user` is nil. What do I have to do to get the `current_user` accessible via warden?

Comment: I have very similar Connection and have found that after reloading the page several times, then user shows up.  It feels like a race condition between loading the session and establishing the Connection, but I haven't been able to track down where it is.